# Python printing a 2D list with infinite user inputs

Tags: python

I'm trying to complete this code where it will ask the user for an input of what their name is and what their favorite food is and it will continously ask the user if they want to add more data. At the point where the user inputs 'N' I need the full table to print out with all of the inputs together, anyone know how to do this instead of just one by one?

```
def get_string_inputs (p) :
    ''' requests the string data and returns it'''
    strData=input("Please enter {0} : ".format(p))
    return strData

def add_data_rows () :
    ''' adds data to the row array'''
    meal_details = [ ]
    #the helper function is used here
    name = get_string_inputs("your name ").capitalize()
    meal_details.append(name)
    favourite_meal = get_string_inputs("your favourite food").capitalize()
    meal_details.append(favourite_meal)
    return meal_details

def main() :
    '''runs all functions'''
    favMeal = []
    header=['Name','Favourite Meal']
    favMeal.append(header)

    meal_details = add_data_rows()
    favMeal.append(meal_details)
    for a,b in favMeal:
        print('{0:16}{1:<16}'.format(a,b))
    while True:    
        valid_option = ['Y','N']
        question = input("Would you like to add more data? (Y/N): ").upper()
        if question in valid_option:
            if question == 'Y' :
                main()
            if question == 'N' :
                ??????
        break
    else:
        print("That is not a valid choice, Please enter Y or N")
main()
```

Comment: So you mean that you want to output the list with only a single call to `print` and not looping through your list printing the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a couple things out of place, I made notes on the lines that I changed. 
I hope this helps.

```
def get_string_inputs (p) :
    ''' requests the string data and returns it'''
    strData=input("Please enter {0} : ".format(p))
    return strData

def add_data_rows () :
    ''' adds data to the row array'''
    meal_details = [ ]
    #the helper function is used here
    name = get_string_inputs("your name ").capitalize()
    meal_details.append(name)
    favourite_meal = get_string_inputs("your favourite food").capitalize()
    meal_details.append(favourite_meal)
    return meal_details

def main() :
    '''runs all functions'''
    favMeal = []
    header=['Name','Favourite Meal']  # Add the header row
    favMeal.append(header)
    meal_details = add_data_rows()  # Now add the first row
    favMeal.append(meal_details)
    valid_option = ['Y', 'N']  # Just do this once, not every time the loop happens
    while True:  # Now add rows until they say N
        question = input("Would you like to add more data? (Y/N): ").upper()
        if question in valid_option:
            if question == 'Y' :
                favMeal.append(add_data_rows())  # Here we just call the function that adds a row, and append the results that it returns
            if question == 'N' :
                break # Break the while loop if they answer N
        else:
            print("That is not a valid choice, Please enter Y or N")
    for a,b in favMeal: # Now print everything
        print('{0:16}{1:<16}'.format(a,b))
main()
```

Comment: Works perfectly, didn't realize you didn't have to put the main in the loop so it repeats. Thanks!